# Angular 4 ngComponentOutlet and lazy loading modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I am currently starting to get the hang of angular 4 , specifically the dynamic components part.

I managed to replicate with success the **ngComponentOutlet** approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065289), plunkr [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/9L72KpobVvY14uiQjo4p/)

Now what i would like to do is lazy loading a module containing the dynamic component. I see [on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14043) that this feature should have been implemented but i'm not experienced enough  in angular 4 to interpret the source changes myself, and i can't find anywhere an example of this approach.

Also, i'd like to achieve this kind of lazy loading without depending on the a4 router and with webpack (if it matters).

Anybody willing to help?

TIA

Comment: Did you look at [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)?

Comment: This article should give you all the answers [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e). Ask clarification questions here

Comment: Sir you made my day, i didn't know about **compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync**. Very nice article, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jurito, you're welcome) you can follow me for more in-depth articles

Comment: @Maximus You can also post it as answer

Comment: @yurzui, done, thanks)

Comment: @jurito, please consider accepting my answer if it helped. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` of the compiler. Something along these lines:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  System.import('app/t.module').then((module) => {
      _compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.TModule)
        .then((compiled) => {
          const m = compiled.ngModuleFactory.create(this._injector);
          const factory = compiled.componentFactories[0];
          const cmp = factory.create(this._injector, [], null, m);
        })
    })
}
```

For more information read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e).